# Making each account have a separate S3 bucket for attachments using Shrine

Tags: ruby, shrine

In our Ruby I would like that each account has a separate S3 bucket for its attachments. I would also like that bucket names can be derived from account's attributes:

```
Account(id: 1, username: "johnny") # uses the "1-johnny" bucket
Account(id: 2, username: "peter")  # uses the "2-peter" bucket
# ...
```

Is something like this possible to do in [Shrine](https://github.com/janko-m/shrine)?

Comment: Are you aware that the default [maximum number of buckets is 100](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html)?. This might be a problem when you get more users...

Comment: Thanks for noting, I wasn't aware of it. This can still be used for cases where there are limited number of users (e.g. for managers of an event).

Comment: Google cloud storage does not have a limit on the total number of buckets, but disappointingly, the names possible are not scoped by account. for example, if you create a bucket called "test" then i cannot create another one called "test". in other words, the names must be unique across the whole world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. First you use the `default_storage` plugin to dynamically assign storage names:

```
Shrine.plugin :default_storage, store: ->(record, name) do
  "store_#{record.id}_#{record.username}"
end

# store_1_johnny
# store_2_peter
```

Next you use the `dynamic_storage` plugin to dynamically instantiate S3 storages based on the identifier:

```
Shrine.plugin :dynamic_storage

Shrine.storage /store_(\d+)_(\w+)/ do |match|
  bucket_name = "#{match[1]}_#{match[2]}"
  Shrine::Storage::S3.new(bucket: bucket_name, **s3_options)
end

# 1-johnny
# 2-peter
```